# Child Selector jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, children

I have a jQuery object contained in `this`.

When I call:

```
console.log($(this).children("td.price.desired").html());
```

The terminal prints:

```
<h3 class="table-label"><span class="label label-default number"> 0 </span></h3>
<input name="trade_params[0][price_desired]" type="number" step="0.01" value="0" min="0.00" class="form-control number" placeholder="Chart Price">
```

My aim is actually to get hold of the element with the `<h3>`tag.

However, when I call:

```
console.log($(this).children("td.price.desired h3").html());
```

I am told that the result is undefined.

My understanding is that I can use the selector method for ancestor and child documented here: http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/.

I can get hold of `<h3>` with:

```
$(this).children("td.price.desired").children("h3")
```

What am I doing wrong in the first method? To me, both methods are supposed to be equivalent.

**EDIT:**

Here is the full HTML in context:

```
<tr class="0">
    <td class="price desired">
        <h3 class="table-label"><span class="label label-default number"> 0 </span></h3>
        <input name="trade_params[0][price_desired]" type="number" step="0.01" value="0" min="0.00" class="form-control number" placeholder="Chart Price">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Use [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) instead

Answer (score 2):

[.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) just looks for the direct child of the element, in this case you need to use [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
console.log($(this).find("> td.price.desired h3").html());
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/CEZd6/)

Comment: But isn't `<h3>` a direct descendant?

Comment: @SavvasNicholas not of the `tr` element referred by `this`

Comment: The `this` element refers to `tr` right? So surely `h3` is a direct descendant of `tr`, or have i got this entirely wrong?

Comment: @SavvasNicholas sorry I think I confused you by using descendant, it is not a direct child of tr, the `h3` is a child of `td` which is a child of `tr`

Comment: Ok, but doesn't `td.price.desired` refer to the `td` element, and then `h3` should then target descendants of that? I don't see the point of the Parent Descendant selector otherwise. In their example in the documentation, it has it traversing multiple levels of the document tree. Should I be using `filter` instead of `children`?

Answer (score -1):

try

```
console.log($(this).children("td.price.desired > h3").html());
```

Comment: What is the difference between that and without the `>` sign?

Comment: using the > selector gets only the first level children, whereas without it will grab all descendants.